# Solution to diophantine equation in $x_0$ and $y_0$

Tags: number-theory

My problem says: 
Suppose that ($x_0,y_0$) is a solution to the Diophantine equation 47X+6Y=1. Using the fact that 6=100-2*47, find a solution to the Diophantine equation 100X+47Y=1 in terms of $x_0$ and $y_0$.

I found (x,y)=(8, -17) but I don't know how that relates to the fact given and to $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
 &47 x_0 + 6 y_0 = 1 \\
\implies &47 x_0 +  (100 - 2 \times 47 ) y_0 = 1  \\
\implies &100y_0 + 47 (x_0 - 2 y_0) = 1
\end{align}

So, if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution to the first equation, then $(x,y) = (y_0, x_0 - 2y_0)$ is a solution to the second.

Comment: Why did you start with $47 x_0 + 6 y_0 = 1$

Comment: Because that's what's given to me, that $(x_0, y_0)$ satisfies that relation. You could start with the second and prove something similar: if $(x,y)$ is a solution to the second equation, then $(y+2x, x)$ is a solution to the first.